# How do I select all text in Vi/Vim?

Tags: shell, vi

Using VI tool for editing config files.

How can I select all the text in a file (around 1000 lines), copy it, then paste into Google Docs?

Answer (score 205):

The simplest and fastest way is to use: <kbd>:</kbd> <kbd>%</kbd> <kbd>y</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> and then go over to Google Docs (or wherever) and paste.
Explanation:

- <kbd>%</kbd>  to refer the next command to work on all the lines
- <kbd>y</kbd>  to yank those lines
- <kbd>+</kbd>  to copy to the system clipboard

Another way is <kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>y</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> but you will likely admit that the above is faster and easier.

Comment: +1 for the first method, another benefit is that it doesn't move the cursor position.

Comment: @Tuxmentat can you please explain what each key does in `:%y+`

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained what each key does for both sequences.

Comment: My best guess:  the ':' means we're using an "ex mode" command (I think). Anyhow, it's a command. '%' is a special [command-line range specifier](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#cmdline-ranges) which specifies the whole file. 'y' yanks everything, and '+' specifies the [clipboard register](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#registers).  :help <command> helped me figure this out.

Comment: ggVG, then "+y is my fav, and then of course i dont use "+ because i mapped y to "+y (among others) that way i just have to do ggVG and then y

Comment: @HawkeyeParker probably here's is some secret anyway because with this logic the `:%p+` should have worked too, but it doesn't ☹

Comment: If you are in Windows and have `set clipboard=unnamed` in your .vimrc, you can simply use `:%y`

Comment: i must be doing something wrong. i type `:%y+`, and i get `E488: Trailing characters`

Comment: I get "E850: Invalid register name". Second method worked fine for copying, but doesn't get to system clipboard on Ubuntu 16.04 (for me, at least---I have a .vimrc that may be affecting things).

Comment: @johnywhy run `:version` and see if `+clipboard` is there ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7943665/264047))

Comment: @EntangledLoops you will get that error if clipboard support is not compiled in. Try downloading `gvim`, or better, NeoVim (for all its performance improvements)

Comment: @oligofren Thanks, good to know and gvim worked. The original poster was asking about VI though, so not sure these are ideal solutions.

Comment: @EntangledLoops, I have a quite virgin vimrc and still got the same problem, but if you use split screen by `:sp file2_name`, you can past it with p. And I still think there has to be a better way to do it.

Comment: This solution is not working. It's not as well as its votes!

Comment: @alexjolig @entangledloops Not sure if that command for older versions, but for recent versions of Vi (7.4 onwards), this answer is wrong in the sense that it requires  `: % + y` and not `: % y +` (note the position of the plus symbol). Hope that saves someone a few agonising minutes. [credits to RL]

Comment: I use ":1,$ y"

Which means : <- Command mode, 1 <- line number 1 $ <- last line y <- yank

Comment: I worked like a charm on gvim windows. @Tuxmentat

Comment: I don't know why this has so many upvotes, it doesn't answer the question as stated. This is how you "copy all to clipboard", not "select all".

Comment: :%y+   does not work for me. I receive E850: Invalid register name

Comment: You can use :%c for clear all note

Comment: This alternative may be easier to stretch your fingers to: `:%y *`
Note the space between `y` and `*`.

Answer (score 131):

Many given replies also yank the selection, which I was not looking for.

I'm using <kbd>ggVG</kbd> for this purpose (needs to be run on normal mode). This command *only* selects the whole text inside the document.

I've even remapped <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> for this purpose, since I don't really need to increment an integer with the shortcut (default <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> map).

Just add this into your `.vimrc`:

```
map <C-a> <esc>ggVG<CR>
```

It has `<esc>` first, to make sure the user is in normal mode.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, and it's nice to see that Ctrl+A isn't occupied in vim by default. Hope there are no side-effects.

Comment: I personally use `ggVG`, but `gg0vG$` might be more appropriate since it more closely replicates the 'normal' Ctrl+A operation.

Answer (score 48):

You can use `cat file` and then select output and copy and paste if you need to paste it into your browser.

For vi this is how you can select all text and write it into a new file:

```
shift v  -- visual mode
shift g -- jump to eof
"*y -- yank select text
:e my_new_file -- create a new file
"*p -- paste into a new file
```

In theory this should work on both Linux and Windows - I tried it on a Mac but it doesn't work.

Comment: To paste into the Web browser `cat file` is the way to go. The `shift v` method only copies to Vi's internal buffer.

Comment: not if you use the system clipboard which uses the * registry - but this works on X only and I heard on windows - so if you ssh you need the -X  - to check if vim has support for this into vim -- :set clipboard+=unnamed

Comment: Is there any alternative to do this without creating a new file.if we are editing live on server we need to keep the backup code on local machine so that we can revert back.

Comment: +1 for cat and select in putty. Of course, will not work for huge files and is not the most user friendly method. But for copying small script files which goes outside screen viewport is good enough.

Answer (score 23):

USE ggVG.
type "gg" to go at top of the test 
Then type VG.

Answer (score 14):

I am using Vim 7.4 in CentOS-7 environment. Which worked me for selecting all the text is

```
:%y
```

Then just `p` in the next file where I want a full copy.

**Or**

You can use cat command.

`cat copyfile > pastefile`

[This git repo](https://gist.github.com/Steven-Rose/3943830) has some other useful commands too.

Comment: This is the best shortcut than any other codes. I have tested this and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 9):

`gg"+yG`

or

`gg"*yG`

depending on whether + or * is the system clipboard. (On many unixes, + is the mouse selection buffer for middle-mouse-clicking, and * is the system clipboard).

Comment: I think it's the other way around: "* is selection and "+ is clipboard. http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui_x11.html#x11-selection

Comment: You're right. I knew that too, but typed the wrong thing. ☹

Answer (score 5):

For a Mac, use pbcopy (pasteboard copy):

```
cat file.txt | pbcopy
```

The contents of file.txt are now on the clipboard for pasting into another application (e.g. browser).

You can also paste the contents of the clipboard into a file using pbpaste:

```
pbpaste > file.txt
```

While this doesn't involve vi specifically it does achieve the same goal on a Mac.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a linux desktop, you could load it into the clipboard using xclip or xsel.  For something that size you might just want to use the upload feature in google docs.

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be:

You press <kbd>v</kbd> key on your keyboard and turn VIM to VISUAL

Then select all text by scrolling down

<kbd>^</kbd>+ <kbd>INSERT</kbd> to copy

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> +<kbd>INSERT</kbd> to paste the text wherever you want on Google Docs.

Answer (score 0):

Without using vi, [you can upload text to google docs using their API and cURL](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/gdata/articles/using_cURL.html).

Comment: that's the opposite of what OP wants -.-

Answer (score 0):

See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard for options on how to do this.  (if compiled in "* should refer to the system clipboard).  There are also instructions there for how to use xsel with vim.

Comment: "* is the what was selected and "+ is what was copied. http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui_x11.html#x11-selection

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command.

```
cat <your file name>
```

It will echo the content of file. Now select, scroll, copy, paste.
Game Over

Ex.:

```
cat bobis.txt
```